# Get local Date as long in android, confusion maybe?

Tags: java, android, date

I might have little confusion about Date in android/java. What I know is when calling `new Date()` it creates a `Date` instance with current UTC date and time, Right ? Because `Date` in java don't have any time zone thing, So if I call
`new Date().getTime()` I will get a `long` value(time stamp) as UTC, not as local time, right ?

And to show date, we use 'DateFormat' and it has time zone info. So when I call `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date())` I will get a `string` with local time.

But how do I get long value(time stamp) of local time ?? I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18692993/836308) but is that the only way ? or something more simple ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

> So if I call `new Date().getTime()` I will get a long value(time stamp) as UTC, not as local time, right?

Well, it will give you the number of milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970 00:00:00 UTC, yes. It's not "in" UTC particularly; it's just a number of milliseconds since an arbitrary epoch.

> But how do I get long value(time stamp) of local time?

You don't, basically. That turns out not to be a particularly useful concept. If you think about it, a timestamp is just an instant in time - it's independent of time zones. You *can* express the Unix epoch in any time zone; it just happens to normally be expressed in terms of UTC.

If you need the local date/time for a particular timestamp, you just need to remember the timestamp itself and the relevant time zone. If you give us more information about what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

See Date.getTime javadocs: `Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object`. There is no local timestamp. There can be only different textual date / time representations of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these to get local date.

```
String s=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date());
```

or

```
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> But how do I get long value(time stamp) of local time ??

A local date-time in a timezone is just a representation of the universal instant in that timezone. The `new java.util.Date()` gives us that universal instant i.e. it simply represents an instant on the timeline — a wrapper around the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). Since it does not hold any timezone information, its **[`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--)** function applies the JVM's timezone to return a `String` in the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`, derived from this ***milliseconds*** value. In other words, the same milliseconds will be represented as different date-times in different timezones. The **vice versa**: at any given moment, date-times in different timezones will give us the same number of epoch milliseconds.

## *java.time*

The object corresponding to `new java.util.Date()` in `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API is [`Instant.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now--).

**A demo of `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Let's assume 2021-06-26T23:35:50 is the local date-time in India
        LocalDateTime ldtIndia = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-06-26T23:35:50");
        Instant instant = ldtIndia.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toInstant();
        long millis = instant.toEpochMilli();
        System.out.println(millis);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1624730750000
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/eefo31)

You can convert `Instant` and `java.util.Date` to each other using

[`java.util.Date#from(Instant)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-) and [`java.util.Date#toInstant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>