# How to Convert RFC-1123 date-time formatter, to local time

Tags: java, android, time, utc

I am getting the date-time `Thu, 25 Aug 2016 08:59:00 GMT` in this [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) format in my Android app. I need to convert to local time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java convert UTC timestamp to local DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691376/java-convert-utc-timestamp-to-local-datetime)

Comment: @Mike Not an exact duplicate. The title of this Question mentions this is a certain standardized format, RFC 1123 (though an outdated standard nowadays).

Comment: @Basil Bourque thanks body you got my back

Answer (score 7):

## `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`

The java.time classes can directly parse/generate strings in the [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) via the [`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME) constant.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = 
    ZonedDateTime.parse( 
        "Thu, 25 Aug 2016 08:59:00 GMT" ,  
        DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME 
    ) 
;
```

From there, adjust into your desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );  // Or "Asia/Kolkata", etc.
ZonedDateTime zdtMontreal = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( z );
```

FYI, that [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) format is terrible, and is outdated nowadays. The format’s problems include: assumes English unnecessarily, is difficult to parse, and uses the 3-4 letter zone abbreviations that are not real time zones, not standardized, and are not even unique(!). Instead:

- Specify time zones using [proper IANA-defined time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).
- Serialize to text using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.
  The java.time classes use these formats by default when parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values.

Search Stack Overflow for more information about adjusting time zones and generating Strings of date-time values.

### Localized content

If your goal is to generate text for presentation to a user, rather than use RFC 1123 format, generate localized text. For localized content,  just use [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle dateTimeStyle ).withLocale( Locale locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime(java.time.format.FormatStyle)).

For example, for a United States user, `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( Locale.US )`. Or, to use the JVM’s current default `Locale`, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( … )`.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
    .withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/sduZBx).

> Monday, June 5, 2023 at 10:30:43 AM Japan Standard Time

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: It's tough to construe "Assumes English" as something that makes RFC 1123 terrible.

Comment: @Kröw Wow, if you can’t see why a world-wide international standard for the most basic information element *unnecessarily* requiring a language spoken by a minority of the earth’s people is a bad idea, I don’t think I could explain it to you. Your comment is all the more ironic given the non-English [umlaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umlaut_(diacritic)) in your user name.

Comment: Please keep an open mind to the possible use cases of `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`. It will help you understand. If someone is printing times to `String`s that only they will ever read, they don't *need* it to be compatible with every language in existence, just their own. This is precisely one of the reasons I was saying that it's tough to construe "Assumes English" as making RFC 1123 terrible; it's not realistic to think that it assuming English "requires" anyone to know any language, it just changes its use case. Unrealistically disregarding this is precisely that tough construal.

Comment: @Kröw For localized content,  just use [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle dateTimeStyle ).withLocale( Locale locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime(java.time.format.FormatStyle)). For example, for a United States user, `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( Locale.US )`. Or just `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )` to use the JVM’s current default `Locale`.